# How to getting directory path from file path in batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am very new to Command script please help in below question.

I have below for loop which returns the paths of the files available in `C:\test` folder and its subfolders. I want the directory path from the file path For example.

If for loop returns `C:\test\scripts\sample.txt` but i want only  `C:\test\scripts`. for this i have written below command to

```
For /R C:\seq\ %%a IN (*) do (
set filename="%%a"
echo %filename%
)
```

This is not assigning file path to variable filename so i can get directory path out of it. Please help in getting directory path from file path in batch scripting.

Comment: Look at `for /?` especially the `~`-modifiers

Answer (score 1):

To get the path to the parent directory of a file or directory, use the [`~dp` modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) variable references. In case the trailing `\` disturbs, you can use another `for` loop, like below:

```cmd
for /R "C:\test\scripts" %%I IN ("*.txt") do (
    echo Path to parent with trailing `\`: "%%~dpI"
    echo Path to parent with trailing `\.`: "%%~dpI."
    for /D %%J in ("%%~dpI.") do (
        echo Pure path to parent: "%%~fJ"
    )
)
```

Let me recommend to **not** remove the trailing backslash by [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) (which you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for when doing it within the loop, as others already said), because there might be situations where the resulting path does no longer point to the original location. For instance, a path `D:\` points to the *root* directory of drive `D:`; after removing the `\`, the path is `D:`, which points to the *current* directory of the drive. Using the above technique avoids such problems.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `dp` modifier:

```
set filename=%%~dpa
```

Also, to `echo` the variable, you'll need to expand it with delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /R C:\seq\ %%a IN (*) do (
set filename="%%a"
echo !filename!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For /R C:\seq\ %%a IN (*) do (
set filename="%%~dpa"
call echo %%filename:~0,-1%%
)
```

Please see many SO articles about `delayed expansion` for other ways to show `filename`.

The `~dp` assigns the drive and path of `%%a`.

see `for /?|more` from the prompt for information

The `:~0,-1` in the `echo` selects all characters bar the final one

see `set /?` from the prompt for documentation